# Loading all of the db table once vs Loading needed parts in a loop in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, memory

I have two approaches on working on a DB table.

First:

```
var mylist = db.DBTable.ToList(); 
foreach(var element from anotherlist)
{
 //do operations on necessary parts of mylist and element from the loop
}
```

Second :

```
foreach(var element from anotherlist)
{
 var mypartoflist = db.DBTable.Where(/*some condition*/).ToList(); 
 //do operations on mypartoflist and element from the loop
}
```

First approach works a lot faster than the second one, like more than 10 times faster. But it uses more memory. As you can predict, second one uses less memory but it is awfully slow. Is there a third approach which works as fast as the first one but it uses less memory like the second one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your first choice is the right way to do that. I you make SQL calls inside a loop you'll make tons of network (or interprocess) calls to the SQL Server.

The memory usage is relative, it depends on the Garbage collector. If you tell me that your process is taking 16GB RAM, you're getting "out of memory" errors and you're returning like 2 million rows, you could try to fetch data in pages, something like this:

```
var recordCount = GetRecordCount();
var processed = 0;
while(processed < recordCount){
    var mylist = GetNextBatch(processed, 1000); //Fetch next 1000
    foreach(var element from anoterlist)
    {
         //do operations on necessary parts of mylist and element from the loop
    }
    processed += 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General rule of thumb is you'll trade memory for processing time - this is the [Space-Time trade off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff)

In your second example, you executing multiple statements against the database, so are making a call to a dependency outside of your system boundary - something that is usually expensive and to be avoided where possible.

In your first example, the question you need to answer is - does it matter if you use a bit of memory here? If the table you're working against is small, e.g. for lookup data, then it probably doesn't and this approach is fine. If that contains many 1000 records, then that's a different problem to solve.

You've either got to get all the data, or get it in chunks, then determine how often that is going to happen. In the end, the most expensive call is usually across the system boundary, and this is what you want to minimise.

I'd choose using up some memory over making lots of database calls - depending on the size of the data.